# How can I do join in django?

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-queryset

I'm working with django, expecially with QuerySet right now and I have a very big problem.
so, this is my code:

```
resources_rights = Resources_rights.objects.filter( group_id__in = groups )
resources = Resources.objects.filter( id__in = resources_rights__resource_id
```

)

**Resources_rights** refers to a models that have *resource_id*, *group_id*, *read*, *write* and *execute*.
**Resources**, instead, contains *last_modify*, *name*, *description* and of course the *id*.

So, in **resource_rights** I save some objects and everyone has his *resource_id*.

I would filter **Resources** using *resource_id* fields in **resource_rights**, but like I had do is not possible because the first query returns objects.

So, how can I do? there is an operator for that?

thank you all!

**Edit:**
models are:

```
class Resources_rights(models.Model):
    resource_id = models.IntegerField( db_column='resource_id' )
    group_id = models.IntegerField(Groups, db_column='group_id' )
    read = models.BooleanField( db_column='read' )
    write = models.BooleanField( db_column='write' )
    execute = models.BooleanField( db_column='execute' )
    class Meta:
        db_table = u'sso_resource_permissions'

class Resources(models.Model):
    last_modify = models.DateField( db_column='last_modify' )
    resource_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_column='resource_name' )
    description = models.TextField()
    class Meta:
        db_table = u'sso_resources'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to join instead doing `in`:

```
resources = Resources.objects.filter(resources_rights__group_id__in=groups)
```

Comment: Thank you @Ivan, it is right what I'm trying to do; but it returns me an error: FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'resources_rights' into field. Choices are: description, id, last_modify, resource_name. It seems that it takes 'resources_rights' as a Resources field

Comment: Why do you have `IntegerField` for resource_id? You should change it to `resource = models.ForeignKey(Resources, on_delete=models.CASCADE)` and then use the query from my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much Ivan! you really saved me!

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [values_list()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#values-list). With them you can do something like:

```
resources_rights_ids = Resources_rights.objects.filter( group_id__in = groups ).values_list('id', flat=True)
resources = Resources.objects.filter( id__in = resources_rights_ids )
```

(not tested)

Comment: You have both right, but I would all Resources_rights fields in resources_rights because I have to reuse this result and do another query for redoing the same is a waste.

Answer (score 0):

```
resources_rights = Resources_rights.objects.filter(group_id__in = groups).values_list('resource_id')
resources = Resources.objects.filter( id__in = resources_rights )
```